# return false to terminate nested each loop not working

Tags: jquery

I have used return false to terminate each loop but it is not breaking the loop.
My code is as below :

```
$.each(popuparray, function (i, item) {
    $('.droparea >.ss-active-child').each(function () {
        if (this.id == finaldivId) {
            alert("this is " + this.id + "  finaldivId  " + finaldivId);
            return false;
        }
    });
    //some code here as well
});
```

Kindly suggest me the solution.

Comment: you want both loops to exit?

Comment: Yes I want to exit both loop.

Comment: see my answer hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to declare one flag and switch it based on the internal loop's flow and based on that flag decide the outer loop's flow,

```
var xCondition = false;

$.each(popuparray, function (i, item) {
    $('.droparea >.ss-active-child').each(function () {
        if (this.id == finaldivId) {
            alert("this is " + this.id + "  finaldivId  " + finaldivId);
            xCondition = true;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if(xCondition){ xCondition = false; return false; }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from the out loop also, you can use a flag variable to keep track of the valid state in the inner loop, and return its value from the outer one.

```
$.each(popuparray, function (i, item) {
    var flag = true;
    $('.droparea >.ss-active-child').each(function () {
        if (this.id == finaldivId) {
            alert("this is " + this.id + "  finaldivId  " + finaldivId);
            flag = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    //some code here as well
    return flag;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both loop to exit on condition then do like this:

```
$.each(popuparray, function (i, item) {
    var flag = true;
    $('.droparea >.ss-active-child').each(function () {
        if (this.id == finaldivId) {
            alert("this is " + this.id + "  finaldivId  " + finaldivId);
            flag = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
if(!flag)
{
  return false;
}   

});
```

**Note:** return true acts as continue so you need to check the flag and then return false in outer loop.

Comment: Note `return true` will act as `continue`